# Azure Active Directory - how to assign application role to group programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am looking to create a role based authorization mvc application using Azure AD:

- [Create a .NET MVC web app in Azure App Service with Azure Active Directory authentication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-lob-application-azure-ad/)
- [Azure Role-based Access Control](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/)

From the Azure Portal, I am able :

- To create user and groups.
- To assign user to group.
- To create applications roles.
- To create application roles (by modifying the manifest)
- To assign an application role to a user.

I've just had a **free Azure Active Directory edition** and I've readed that we can use the [Microsoft Azure Active Directory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient/) to perform these actions :

- To assign multiple application roles to users.
- To assign multiple application roles to groups.

Microsoft provides [good samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web) to query the AAD and I've started with it but I can't figured out how to assign an application to a group.

Here is my pseudo code to get the group:

```
ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
var app = (await client.Applications.GetByObjectId("applicationObjectId").ExecuteAsync());
var servicePrincipal = await client.ServicePrincipals.GetByObjectId("servicePrincipalObjectId").ExecuteAsync();
var appRole = app.AppRoles.First(r => r.DisplayName == "my role");
var mygroup = (await client.Groups.ExecuteAsync()).CurrentPage.FirstOrDefault();
```

What I would like to do is something like that :

```
mygroup .AppRoleAssignments.Add(new AppRoleAssignment()
{
    ResourceId = Guid.Parse(servicePrincipal.ObjectId),
    Id = appRole.Id,
    PrincipalType = "Group",
    PrincipalId = Guid.Parse(mygroup .ObjectId),
});
await group.UpdateAsync();
```

But the type of the AppRoleAssignments is `IPagedCollection<IAppRoleAssignment>` and there is no Add method.

Does anyone knows what I need to chage in my code ?

Comment: according to
http://www.dushyantgill.com/blog/2014/12/10/roles-based-access-control-in-cloud-applications-using-azure-ad/ 
If the customers’ organization has AAD premium, they can also assign groups to the application using the same user experience.

Comment: Yes but you need to pay ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact it was simple... I had to cast the IGroup as a `Group` :

```
ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
var app = (await client.Applications.GetByObjectId("applicationObjectId").ExecuteAsync());
var servicePrincipal = await client.ServicePrincipals.GetByObjectId("servicePrincipalObjectId").ExecuteAsync();
var appRole = app.AppRoles.First(r => r.DisplayName == "my role");
var mygroup = (Group)(await client.Groups.ExecuteAsync()).CurrentPage.FirstOrDefault();
```

And it works fine ^^ :

```
mygroup .AppRoleAssignments.Add(new AppRoleAssignment()
{
    ResourceId = Guid.Parse(servicePrincipal.ObjectId),
    Id = appRole.Id,
    PrincipalType = "Group",
    PrincipalId = Guid.Parse(mygroup .ObjectId),
});
await group.UpdateAsync();
```